# JButtons cutoff on bottom of window

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I've been learning how to make GUIs in Java, and as part of an assignment, we're required to have two rows of buttons, one above the other. I have all of the buttons, but the bottom ones are being cutoff about halfway. I cannot figure out how to get them to display fully. I've tried adjusting the Y-size of the window, but they still remain cutoff. Does anyone have any idea on how I can get the bottom three buttons to fully display?
[Image of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9pp4.png)

The relevant code

```
JPanel rightA = new JPanel();
JPanel bottomB = new JPanel();
JPanel bottomB2 = new JPanel();
JLabel jlName = new JLabel("Item Name: ");
JLabel jlNum = new JLabel("Number of: ");
JLabel jlCost = new JLabel("Cost: ");
JLabel jlOwed = new JLabel("Amount Owed: ");
JButton jbCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
JButton jbSave = new JButton("Save");
JButton jbClear = new JButton("Clear");
JButton jbExit = new JButton("Exit");
JButton jbLoad = new JButton("Load");
JButton jbPrev = new JButton("<Prev");
JButton jbNext = new JButton("Next>");
this.setTitle("Items Order Calculator");
this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
rightA.add(jlName);
rightA.add(jtfName);
rightA.add(jlNum);
rightA.add(jtfNum);
rightA.add(jlCost);
rightA.add(jtfCost);
rightA.add(jlOwed);
rightA.add(jtfOwed);
bottomB.add(jbCalculate);
bottomB.add(jbSave);
bottomB.add(jbClear);
bottomB.add(jbExit);
bottomB2.add(jbLoad);
bottomB2.add(jbPrev);
bottomB2.add(jbNext);
jtfOwed.setEnabled(false);
rightA.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
this.add(rightA, BorderLayout.EAST);
bottomB.add(bottomB2);
this.add(bottomB, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `this.pack()` before setting it visible?

Comment: You should call `rightA.setLayout(...)` *before* you add components to that panel.

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak When I use this.pack(), I get [this as a result](https://i.imgur.com/IuBJWUk.png) whereas I need two rows, similar to [this](https://i.imgur.com/Eo7osIU.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding the bottomB2 panel into the bottomB panel and they are not communicating their preferred sizes properly.

Try instead creating another panel with border layout and add them into north and south areas of this panel. Then add this new bottom panel into your gui at south.

```
JPanel bottomAll = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
bottomAll.add(bottomB, BorderLayout.NORTH);
bottomAll.add(bottomB2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.add(bottomAll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! I didn't even think about the two panels communicating their own sizes to each other.